# Обобщить/Создать сервис с (window, 'resize') | Angular 8

Tags: angular, адаптивная-верстка, responsive

Для реактивного изменения активного html блока для адаптивного интерфейса я использую следующий код

```
<div class="p-0 m-0" *ngIf="!mobileMode">
</div>

<div class="p-0 m-0" *ngIf="mobileMode">
</div>
```

```html
import { Observable, Subscription, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

export class FullStackComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    resizeObservable$: Observable<Event>;
    resizeSubscription$: Subscription;
    mobileMode = false;

    ngOnInit() {
    this.checkResolution();
    this.resizeObservable$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize');
    this.resizeSubscription$ = this.resizeObservable$.subscribe(evt => {
      this.checkResolution();
    });
  }
  checkResolution() {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width < 1024) {
      this.mobileMode = true;
    } else {
      this.mobileMode = false;
    }
  }
  
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.resizeSubscription$.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Работает хорошо. Но вот у меня около 30 страниц и компонентов. Заталкивать такое в каждый компонент не хотелось бы. Как можно это все вынести в сервис. Ведь как я понимаю в сервисе нету OnInit. Возможно использовать не сервис а дерективу, которая будет прятать блок. Для справки, ранее использовал ngx-responsive, но данная библиотека не реактивна и меняет блок только при загрузке а не изменения браузера в живую в итоге я изменил на такой вариант.

Comment: В чем проблема создать просто поток в компоненте `mobileMOde$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(startWith(null), map(() => window.innerWidth < 1024), share())` и подписываться через `async` в шаблоне? Без кучи ненужных методов `ngOnInit|checkResolution|ngOnDestroy` и дублирования кода в других местах. Либо создать структурную директиву, которая будет скрывать/показывать элемент в зависимости от разрешения, как аналог `ngIf` - `<div class="p-0 m-0" *mobileMode> ...` & `<div class="..." *desktopMode`

Comment: @overthesanity добавил структурную дерективу, работает, но не могу понять, а как мне указать через нее какой шаблон спрятать. На странице два блока, в каждом стоит деректива *appAdaptive  при разрешение меньше 1024 одна должна спрятаться, а так как деректива на обеих блоках, то прячит сразу два блока